# The object is null, however checking if it's null returning false

Tags: c#

I am suffering a weird problem in C# 4.5.

I have this in my model:

```
private DataMatrix<T> _matrix;

public DataMatrix<T> Matrix
{
    get { return _matrix; }
    set { _matrix = value; }
}
```

And I have a property which uses this:

```
public object SingleElement
{
     get
     {
        if (Matrix == null) return String.Empty;

        if (Matrix.ColumnCount >= 1 && Matrix.RowCount >= 1)
        {
           return Matrix[0, 0];
        }
        return null;
     }
 }
```

When I run it, before calling `SingleElement`, the Matrix property is null. But it doesn't return `String.Empty`, it goes to the second if-statement.

That's my Immediate window says:
[image: Immediate window]

I'm a bit confused. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does `Matrix` have an overloaded `==` operator that fails to properly handle null?

Comment: Or perhaps it has an overridden ToString() method that returns "null"?

Comment: What makes you think `Matrix` is `null` ? I kinda suspect that it is non-null.

Comment: See also [MSDN: Viewing Data in the Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esta7c62.aspx). The Immediate Window isn't always the best choice. The easiest would be to hover the mouse over your `Matrix` variable.

Comment: @MarcGravell: The immediate window in the screenshot suggests that `Matrix` is null (unless, as Jon suggested, `ToString()` is just happens to return `null` anyway).

Comment: @MarcGravell It indicates both things, which is the source of the OP's confusion. Either `Matrix` is null and `==` is incorrectly implemented, `Matrix` is not null and `ToString()` returns null for some reason or some third option we haven't considered yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a most likely a broken equality operator (`==`), which can be reproduced with the following code:

```
class Foo
{
    public static bool operator == (Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return false; // probably more complex stuff here in the real code
    }
    public static bool operator != (Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo obj = null;
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
    // note there are two compiler warnings here about GetHashCode/Equals;
    // I am ignoring those for brevity
}
```

now at the breakpoint in the immediate window:

```
?obj
null
?(obj==null)
false
```

Two fixes:

- preferred would be to fix the operator, perhaps adding before anything else:

  ```
  if(ReferenceEquals(x,y)) return true;
  if((object)x == null || (object)y == null) return false;
  // the rest of the code...
  ```
- alternative, if you can't edit that type, is to avoid using the operator; consider using `ReferenceEquals` explicitly in your code, or performing `object`-based `null` checks; for example:

  ```
  if(ReferenceEquals(Matrix, null)) ...
  ```

  or

  ```
  if((object)Matrix == null) ...
  ```

Comment: Wont this "(object)Matrix" throw an exception if "Matrix" object is null? Just a thought.

Comment: @samar: No, it won't. You can cast a null reference to any reference type.

Comment: @samar further: as long as it is a reference-type, that is *basically* a no-op - it just forces the compiler to do a "load", "branch if true/false" (which means non-zero for references) rather than using any operators

Comment: @MarcGravell; Thank you very much for going a step further in explaining it for me.